# Ускорение выполнения кода Python

Tags: python, оптимизация

Всем привет.

У меня есть код, выполнение которого надо ускорить
Программа в списке ищет пары, сумма которых равна `s`. Если таких пар несколько, то в ответ выводится та пара, у которой второй элемент в начальном списке имеет наименьший индекс.

Например: [2,4,3,6,3,6], 6
В ответе будет [2,4]

```
def sum_pairs(ints: list, s: int):
    ints_set = list(set(ints))
    results = {}        
    cashe = set()
    for i in range(len(ints_set) - 1):
        for j in range(i, len(ints_set)):
            if tuple([ints_set[i], ints_set[j]]) in cashe:
                continue
            if ints_set[i] + ints_set[j] == s:
                if ints.index(ints_set[i]) < ints.index(ints_set[j]):
                    results[ints_set[i], ints_set[j]] = ints.index(ints_set[j])
                    cashe.add(tuple([ints_set[i], ints_set[j]]))
                elif ints.index(ints_set[j]) < ints.index(ints_set[i]):
                    results[ints_set[j], ints_set[i]] = ints.index(ints_set[i])
                    cashe.add(tuple([ints_set[j], ints_set[i]]))
                    
    for i in ints_set:
        if ints.count(i) > 1:
            sum_equal_nums = i * 2
            if sum_equal_nums == s:
                results[i, i] = ints.index(i, ints.index(i) + 1)

    if len(results) == 0:
        return None
    
    min_value = min(results.values())

    for k, v in results.items():
        if v == min_value:
            return list(k)
        
    return None
```

Если у кого есть варианты, напишите, пожалуйста

Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Раз вы знаете про множества -  зачем два вложенных цикла делаете?

Comment: Мне казалось, что если я буду двумя циклами проходить по множествам и сравнивать их, а не одним по всему начальному массиву, то время выполнения будет меньше. Но спасибо, все сработало) мотаю на ус

Comment: Два вложенных цикла приводят к тому, что количество операций квадратично (пропорционально  n^2, где n-размер данных, в этом случае - размер множеств)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = [2,4,3,6,3,6]
summ = 6
s = set()
for x in a:
    if summ - x in s:
        print(summ-x, x)
        break
    s.add(x)
```